# No se insertan datos en tabla Fact

Tags: ssis

Estoy tratando de insertar datos a través de un ETL en SSIS pero me aparecen los siguientes errores:

> **[Carga FactVolado [2562]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record
>   is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".**
>
> **[Carga FactVolado [2562]] Error: There was an error with Carga FactVolado.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[iID_Aeropuerto
>   (1)] on Carga FactVolado.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column
>   status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for
>   the column.".**
>
> **[Carga FactVolado [2562]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Carga
>   FactVolado.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code
>   0xC020907D occurred, and the error row disposition on "Carga
>   FactVolado.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on
>   error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
>   component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more
>   information about the failure.**
>
> **[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Carga FactVolado" (2562) failed
>   with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination
>   Input" (2575). The identified component returned an error from the
>   ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the
>   error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.**
>
> **[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Agrega ID_Moneda_Q_Loc" (1554)
>   failed with error code 0xC0047020 while processing input "Merge Join
>   Right Input" (1601). The identified component returned an error from
>   the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but
>   the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.**

Según entiendo es porque se esta violando una restricción de llave foránea. Ya revise pero no tengo registros duplicados y mucho menos nulos. No se por donde más buscar.

Comment: Columns[iID_Aeropuerto (1)] esta columna tiene alguna restringcción?

Comment: Únicamente la de llave foránea.

Comment: Esta usando un MERGE? Creo que ahi esta el error... Podrias agregar una imagen de tu paquete SSIS

Comment: Si estoy usando un Merge Join para cruzar la información de una tabla con la otra y traerme unicamente el ID

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo estás teniendo con la columna **iID_Aeropuerto (1)** y la integridad de la tabla como bien muestra el mensaje "*The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.*"

Revisa las constraints de la tabla  FactVolado y comprueba los datos que estas cargando. Una forma de hacerlo con SSIS es habilitando la visualización de datos en el camino que va hacia el Ole DB Destination

[image: Enable Data Viewer]